# Apache proxypass https to https

Tags: apache, ssl, https, proxy

here is what I tired to do:

1. browser -internet-> https(Apache proxypass)-intranet->(Apache https)
2. both Apaches are installed the ssl certs.(startssl wide card,not self-signed)

Apache error log:

`[client 192.168.2.157] SSL Proxy requested for test.xxx.com:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]`

`[error] proxy: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 192.168.2.157:443 (test.xxx.com)`

Then I tried use apache(on the internet) proxy to https://google.com
and the error log is the same.

However，https to http works. 
browser -internet-> https(Apache proxypass)-intranet->(Apache http)

My config:

```
<VirtualHost  *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxx_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxx_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass  /       https://2w.xxx.com/
    ProxyPassReverse   /       https://2w.xxx.com/
    ServerName test.xxx.com
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error-ssl.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

OR:

```
<VirtualHost  *:443>
    ProxyPass  /       https://google.com/
    ProxyPassReverse   /       https://google.com/
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxx_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxx_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class2.server.ca.pem
    ServerName test.xxx.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Seems like it's not possible for apache to handle https to https?
if apache does not support this how about nginx?

Answer (score 17):

### You should set "SSLProxyEngine On". The following is my example that may give you any idea.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ServerName my.example.com:443
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/example.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/example.key"
    ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l /var/logs/apache/example/error.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
    CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l /var/logs/apache/example/ssl_request.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / https://www.google.com/
    <Location />
        ProxyPassReverse /

        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Location>   
</VirtualHost>
```